# Download excell file with user and password needing to click on a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, download

I am trying to automatize the download of an excel file from a web page that needs user and password. I need the information everyday to process it and I don't want to be doing it manually all the time, so I thought it would be easier to make a program in python so it would be downloaded to my computer everyday. I have an user and password to access the web. The problem is that I have to click on a botton (load) and another one (format excel) once I am in the webpage to download the excell.
I have tried with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from datetime import date

name_day = date.today()
namefile = name_day.strftime("%B%d%Y")
outfilename =( '{}.xls').format(namefile)
url_of_file='https://wwwwwwww'
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
r=requests.get(url_of_file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

df = pd.read_excel(r)
df.head()
```

The code works for pages that have the excell ready to load, but it doesn't work on mine. I need some orientation to solve the problem, as I don't know how to go on with the automatization. Could someone please give me a clue? I have seen program that automatically click on pages for next one but I am totally lost in that field. I have read about selenium but I don't know if that would work in my case.
Thank you.

I automatized the code to download the excel and it works in another pages with the excel ready to download, but I need orientation to know how to proceed with the download buttons in a webpage. I have read about selenium but I don't know if it would work here.

Comment: Generally, when you are clicking buttons on a webpage in order to generate this kind of download, in my experience, one of two things is happening:

You are being directed to a new link, which contains the excel resource. This is the link that you should be using for the address in place of what you have.

OR

The javascript on the page is building the excel resource to display. This would require selenium or similar (But I'm not an expert with that tool).

Comment: Thank you Philip. In my case the javascript page is building the excel resource to display and you can download it pressing a button. The problem is I am completely new to this and it's a huge field, so I need orientation or examples to follow. Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a good fit for questions which are asking for general orientation; the guidelines for asking questions presume that you have made some attempt and have a specific problem that needs to be solved.